# Expectation of rational formula

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

I have two independent normal random variables $x$ & $y$ that are zero mean and unit variance. $a$ & $b$ are positive.
I need to find the mean of $$z=\frac{ax^2y^2}{1 + bx^2}.$$
Any help please?!

Comment: May we presume $x$ and $y$ are independent?  (The inclusion of $y^2$ in the formula for $z$ suggests otherwise, but you haven't stipulated anything about the form of dependence between $x$ and $y$.)  Are you assuming $b \ge 0$?

Comment: What do you know about a and b?  Can you transform to modified coordinates $$u = \frac{x}{ \sqrt {  a  }}$$ or something?  mean of z is linearly scaled by a, so it can be pulled out.  There might be a symbolic trick to work with b, but I am not sure.

Comment: @whuber I edited the question. Yes they are independent, a & b are positive. I am looking for such a transform before trying trigonometric transformations.

Comment: Well, I can get you started. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, 

$$E(Z) = \frac{a}{b}\,E(Y^2)\,E(\frac{bX^2}{1 + bX^2})$$

The term in $E(Y^2)$ is straightforward, so the problem reduces to that of finding $E(\frac{bX^2}{1 + bX^2})$ for a standard normal $X$.

Answer (score 4):

I symbolically evaluated the double integral for the desired expectation in MAPLE as follows (note that I executed expand just so that I could get the image to display better).

```
expand(int(int(a*x^2*y^2/(1+b*x^2)*1/(2*Pi)*exp(-1/2*x^2)*exp(-1/2*y^2),x=-infinity..infinity),y=-infinity..infinity));
```

Here is the result:
[image: MAPLE result]

I checked this result against stochastic simulation for several values of b, and it matches, so I have confidence it is correct.

Here are the numerical results for a = 1 and a few values of b:

```
b = 0.1 --> 0.79214855
b = 1   --> 0.34432046
b = 5   --> 0.11888698
```

Edit: I am bumping this because even if this was a homework problem, by now the OP has probably graduated or flunked out.

Comment: Are you assuming a US academic year in that last sentence? In some places Apr 17 and May 8(/9) are in the same semester.

Comment: Yeah, that was a bit tongue in cheek - actually, at all the schools I went to, those dates fall within the same academic semester or quarter.  The point is, the question was answered, but given no votes or acceptance, is still considered open. And it's been a while.

Comment: The system automatically bumps questions in this state periodically.

Answer (score 3):

**This has an elementary solution.**  It employs a technique often found to be useful when integrating exponentials: a fraction can be expressed in terms of an integral of an exponential function.

---

Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the expectation splits into the product of $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=1$ and

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{aX^2}{1+bX^2}\right) = \frac{a}{b}\left(1 - \frac{1}{b}\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{1/b + X^2}\right)\right).\tag{1}$$

Write $1/b = 2s$ (so that $s=1/(2b)$ is positive, too) and note that for any $x$,

$$\frac{1}{2s + x^2} = \int_0^\infty \exp(-(2s + x^2)t)\mathrm{d}t.$$

Apply Fubini's theorem to compute the expectation before performing this integral:

$$\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{1/b+X^2}\right) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2)\int_0^\infty \exp(-(2s + x^2)t)\mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+2t(2s + x^2)\right)\right) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2 s t}}{\sqrt{1+2t}} \left[\frac{\sqrt{1+2t}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left((1+2t)x^2)\right)\right) \mathrm{d}x\right]\mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2 s t}}{\sqrt{1+2t}} \mathrm{d}t.\tag{2}
}$$

The last equality follows by observing that the integral in brackets is the total probability of a Normal variable (with mean $0$ and variance $1/(1+2t)$), which is just $1$.

A substitution with $1+2t$ as the variable easily expresses this in terms of a $\chi^2(1)$ tail probability (computed as an incomplete Gamma function).  Alternatively--to bring the ideas full circle and get back to Normal distribution probabilities--let's apply an aggressive substitution to clear the denominator in the integrand: letting $x^2 =2s(1+2t)$, deduce $dt = x dx/(2s)$, whence (writing $\Phi$ for the standard normal CDF)

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2 s t}}{\sqrt{1+2t}} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{e^{s}\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{2s}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\sqrt{2s}^\infty\exp(-x^2/2)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{e^{s}\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{2s}}\left(1 - \Phi(\sqrt{2s})\right).$$

Plugging this into $(2)$ and then into $(1)$ and re-expressing $s$ as $1/(2b)$ yields

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{aX^2Y^2}{1+bX^2}\right) = \frac{a}{b}\left(1 - e^{1/(2b)}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{b}}\left(1 - \Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\right)\right)\right).$$

Comment: This matches my answer obtained using MAPLE.

Answer (score 1):

No real answer, but it makes things more simple:

$$\mathbb{E}Z=\mathbb{E}\frac{aX^{2}Y^{2}}{1+bX^{2}}=\frac{a}{b}\mathbb{E}Y^{2}\mathbb{E}\frac{bX^{2}}{1+bX^{2}}=\frac{a}{b}\mathbb{E}\left[1-\frac{1}{1+bX^{2}}\right]=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a}{b}\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{1+bX^{2}}$$

So actually to be found is $$\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{1+bX^{2}}$$
where $X$ has standard normal distribution.